# Determine whether $f(x)={\sin x \over x}$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Determine whether the function$$f(x)={\sin x \over x}$$is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am using the definition that for $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.

Comment: Do you know a sufficient condition for a differentiable function to be uniformly continuous?

Comment: NO, I Done !! :( Can this not be done by this definition ?

Comment: Your function isn't defined on $\mathbb R$. Do you also want $f(0) = 1$?

Comment: It can be done, but if you know a simple sufficient criterion, you can check that, and if it's fulfilled, happily go home.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sir, I doubt a quick method will fetch me sufficient marks ..

Comment: @UmbertoP. No, This is all the question in my book reads

Comment: @DavidMitra yes i can use that fact. But then i'll have to consider negative values as well separately ?

Comment: What do you mean "prove if"? Do you have to prove it, or do you need to determine whether it holds?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo "Determine whether the given function is U.C or not"

Comment: OK, I edited accordingly. The phrasing you used, "Prove if", does not mean anything.

Comment: @AmanMittal Sorry for my last comment, I misread your question. I meant to suggest to use the approach in Siminore's answer below.

Comment: @David: I don't understand actually what Siminore's suggestion is for proving that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(M,\infty)$.  For any function vanishing at infinity and continuous on $\mathbb R$, one can fix $\varepsilon>0$, then choose such an $M$ to make the function small enough outside of $[-M,M]$, rather than choose an $M$ first and show it for all $\varepsilon$.  Wouldn't that be going in circles?

Comment: @Jonas Yes. I didn't read the answer carefully ...

Comment: @AmanMittal As Jonas suggests, you could use properties 1. and 2. of Siminore's answer, and an argument similar to the one I used [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172988/please-prove-uniform-continuity/173003).

Comment: I just added a new answer because I think that a recent mathSE query was incorrectly closed.

Answer (score 44):

One has
$$f(x):={\sin x\over x}=\int_0^1 \cos(\tau x)\ d\tau\ .$$
It follows that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \int_0^1|\cos(\tau x)-\cos(\tau y)|\ d\tau\leq \int_0^1\tau |x-y|\ d\tau={1\over2}|x-y|\ .$$
This proves that $f$ is even Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: Now this is a damn beautiful, simple, elegant and nice answer! +1

Comment: Christian Blatter I have a little doubt. Unless we know the value of $f(0)$ how can we talk about the continuity of $f$ on entire R?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath: The defining formula indeed gives no value for $f(0)$. I have tacitly filled this value in by putting $f(0)=1$, as everyone does.

Comment: fine. doubt is clear

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Can you explain how $|\cos(\tau x)-\cos(\tau y)|\leq\tau|x-y|$ arises, please? Thanks alot.

Comment: @Freeze_S: It is a consequence of the mean value theorem.  If $g(x) = \cos(\tau x)$, then for $x\neq y$ $\dfrac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}=g'(z)$ for some $z$ between $x$ and $y$.  Note that $|g'(z)|\leq \tau$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Even more elementary, we have $$\begin{align}
|\cos(\tau x)-\cos(\tau y)|&=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{\tau(x-y)}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\tau(x+y)}{2}\right)\right|\\\\
&\le |\tau (x-y)|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 9):

The function $f$ has bounded derivative over $\Bbb R$, given by $$f'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}-\frac{\sin{x}}{x^2}$$

It is bounded for $x$ outside a neighborhood of $x=0$. Now note that by definition, the derivative at $0$ is $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left( {\frac{{\sin h}}{h} - 1} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\sin h - h}}{{{h^2}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\cos h - 1}}{{2h}} = 0$$

by an application of L'Hôpital's rule. Thus $f'(0)=0$. Now, note that again $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f'(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{{x\cos x - \sin x}}{{{x^2}}}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{ - x\sin x}}{{2x}} = 0$$ by L'Hopital. Thus $f'$ is continuous over the real line, and bounded. It follows $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, with constant $M=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}|f'(x)|$

Comment: Great answer, in fact you don't even need to use L'Hospital's rule, just $\sin h = h+ O(h^3)$ as $h \to 0$

Comment: @Alex Well, they are all entangled. It's almost the same.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff isnt it just enough to show that the derivative is bounded ?

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

1. $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} =0$;
2. $f$ is continuous (I tacitly assume you have defined $f(0)=1$).

Use 1. to split $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, - M ) \cup [-M,M] \cup (M,+\infty)$, and prove that $f$ is separately UC on each interval. For the middle one, you must know that continuity on a compact set implies uniform continuity.

Comment: I don't understand how you are suggesting to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(M,\infty)$.  It is true of course, but it would easier I think to do the breaking up into $[-M,M]$ vs. $\mathbb R\setminus [-M,M]$ after an $\varepsilon>0$ has been fixed in the proof that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, because $M$ will have to be chosen based on a fixed $\varepsilon$, not to work for all $\varepsilon$.  To prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(M,\infty)$ would be just as much work as showing it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathbb{R} \setminus [-M,M]$ should be easier to deal with than $(-\infty,M) \cup (M,+\infty)$.

Comment: It isn't.  Apparently I was unclear.  I mentioned $(M,\infty)$ for brevity because it is obvious that there is no difference between $(-\infty,-M)$ and $(M,\infty)$.  The problem I have with this answer is that you state your hint as though showing uniform continuity separately on $[-M,M]$ and its complement is significantly easier, without indicating how.  I would say that it is a good idea to use your observations 1. and 2. to prove uniform continuity on all of $\mathbb R$. Note what I wrote in the rest of my comment: You can choose $M$ based on $\varepsilon$, not before.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: It is easier because: The derivative is bounded on $(-\infty,-\varepsilon)\cap(\varepsilon,\infty)$ so the function is uniformly continuous there. Also it is continuous on $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ so by compactness uniformly continuous here, too. Thus it is uniformly continuous on the whole real after fiddling in an adjusting argument for the patching.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Ah ok the derivative is for this example even everywhere bounded. But this technique applies quite well to say $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Thanks, Siminore never replied, but perhaps that is what they had in mind, and that sure does work (the derivative is bounded, as you said in your first comment).  Pedro's answer uses the derivative well.  But that would make point 1 above superfluous, whereas I had in mind a proof that would work for an arbitrary continuous function satisfying $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$.  Siminore never said what proof they have in mind.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: You're welcome. Well, you need point 1 in order to check uniform continuity outside zero. What proof did you have in mind?

Comment: @Freeze_S: No you don't, particularly not if you are going to use boundedness of the derivative as you suggested. The function is Lipschitz, much stronger than uniform continuity, and that is not implied by points 1 and 2. If you *are* going to use point 1 however, you need only continuity.  Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $M>1$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/2$ when $|x|>M$.  Using continuity of $f$ on the compact set $[-2M,2M]$, choose $\delta>0$, (and $\delta<1$) such that for all $x$ and $y$ with $|x|<2M$ and $|y|<2M$, $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: (continued) @Freeze_S: Then for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then either $|x|<2M$ and $|y|<2M$, in which case $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ as in the previous sentence, or $|x|>M$ and $|y|>M$, in which case $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)|+|f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

This query has been used as a reference to justify voting to close
[a new query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903500/prove-that-frac-sinxx-is-uniformly-continuous-on-0-pi-using-ep).  However, the new query specifically requires that $~\epsilon, \delta~$
be employed.  Therefore, I am filling the gap so that the new
query is answered here.

Define $f(x)$ so that $~f(0) = 1,~~$ and
for all $~\displaystyle x \neq 0, ~~f(x) = \frac{\sin ~x}{x}
~\implies$ 
[since $\lim_{x \to 0} ~f(x) ~= ~1$] $~f(x) ~$ is continuous everywhere.

I will employ an $\epsilon, \delta$ approach to demonstrate that $f$ is
uniformly continuous throughout $\mathbb{R}.$  This answer will then constitute
a stronger result than the OP in the new query is asking for.

---

**To Prove**

For any $~\epsilon > 0~$ there exists  $~ \delta > 0 ~$  such that 
$|~f(x) ~-~ f(y) ~| ~<~ \epsilon~$ whenever $~|~x ~-~ y ~| ~<~ \delta$.

---

Let $~g(x) ~\equiv ~x (\cos x) - (\sin x) ~\implies ~g(0) ~= ~0.$ 
Let $~h(x) ~\equiv ~(\sin x) ~- ~x (\cos x) ~- ~x^2 ~\implies ~h(0) ~= ~0.$ 
For any **fixed** value of $~x, ~$ and any **variable** value of $~\delta,$  
$~~~~~~~~~~~~$let $~J_x(\delta) ~\equiv ~f(x) ~- ~f(x + \delta) ~- ~\delta ~\implies ~~J_x(0) ~= ~0.$ 
Let $~k(x) ~\equiv ~f(0) ~- ~f(x) ~- ~x ~\implies ~k(0) ~= ~0.$ 
Let $~m(x) ~\equiv ~(\sin ~x) ~- ~x ~\implies ~m(0) ~= ~0.$

---

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 1:}}$ 
$-\pi/2 ~< ~x ~< ~0 ~\implies ~g(x)  ~> ~0 ~~$ and 
$0  ~< ~x ~< ~\pi/2 ~\implies ~g(x)  ~< ~0.$ 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
$g'(x) ~= ~x (-\sin ~x) ~+ ~(\cos ~x) ~- ~(\cos ~x) ~= ~-x (\sin ~x).$ 
Therefore, 
for $~-\pi/2 ~< ~x ~< ~0, ~g(x) ~$ is strictly decreasing $~~$and 
for $~0 ~< ~x ~< ~\pi/2, ~g(x) ~$ is strictly decreasing.

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 2:}}$ 
For $-\pi/2 ~< ~x ~< ~0, ~f(x) ~$ is strictly increasing $~~$ and 
for $~0 ~< ~x ~< ~\pi/2, ~f(x) ~$ is strictly decreasing. 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
For $\displaystyle ~x ~\neq ~0, ~f'(x) ~= 
~\frac{x (\cos ~x) ~- ~(\sin ~x)}{x^2} ~= ~\frac{g(x)}{x^2}.$ 
Invoke Lemma 1.

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 3:}}$ 
For $0 ~< ~x, ~h(x) ~< ~0 ~~$ and 
for $~x ~< ~0, ~h(x) ~< ~0.$ 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
$h'(x) ~= (\cos ~x) ~+ ~x(\sin ~x) ~- ~(\cos ~x) ~- ~2x$ 
$= ~x(\sin ~x) ~- ~2x  ~= x(\sin ~x - 2).$ 
Noting that $~h(0) ~= ~0,$ 
for $~x ~< ~0, ~h(x) ~$ is strictly increasing $~~$ and 
for $~x ~> ~0, ~h(x) ~$ is strictly decreasing.

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 4:}}$ 
For $~0 ~< ~x, ~0 ~< ~\delta, ~J_x(\delta) < 0.$ 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
$\displaystyle ~J_x(\delta) ~= ~\frac{\sin ~x}{x} ~- ~~\frac{\sin ~(x + \delta)}{x + \delta} ~- ~\delta ~\implies$

$\displaystyle 
~\frac{d ~J_x(\delta)}{d ~\delta} ~= 
~- ~\frac{(x + \delta) (\cos[x + \delta]) ~- ~(\sin[x + \delta])}
{(x + \delta)^2} ~- ~1$

$\displaystyle 
~= ~\frac{(\sin[x + \delta]) ~- ~(x + \delta)(\cos[x + \delta]) ~- ~(x + \delta)^2}{(x + \delta)^2}$

$\displaystyle 
~= ~\frac{h(x + \delta)}{(x + \delta)^2}.$

Invoke Lemma 3, noting that $~J_x(0) ~= ~0.$

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 5:}}$ 
For $~0 ~< ~x ~< \pi/2, ~k(x) < 0.$ 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
Since $~f(0) ~= ~1, ~k(x) ~= ~1 ~- ~f(x) ~- ~x.$

By the analysis in the proof to Lemma 2, 
$\displaystyle k'(x) ~= ~- ~\frac{g(x)}{x^2} ~- ~1 ~= 
 ~\frac{h(x)}{x^2}.$

By Lemma 3,
this implies that for $0 ~< ~x ~< \pi/2, ~k'(x) < 0.$ 
Noting that $~k(x) ~= ~0, ~$ the Lemma is proven.

$\underline{\textbf{Lemma 6:}}$ 
For $~0 ~< ~x, ~m(x) < 0.$ 
$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ 
$m'(x) ~= ~(\cos ~x) ~- ~1 ~\implies$ 
for $~x ~< ~\pi/2,  ~m'(x)~$ is strictly negative. 
Thereafter, $~m'(x)~$ is never $~> ~0.$ 
Therefore, with $~m(0) = 0, ~m(x)$ 
is strictly decreasing on $~(0, ~\pi/2)~$ and 
thereafter, is strictly non-increasing.

$\underline{\text{Identity 7:}}$ 
For $~0 ~< ~|a - b| ~< ~(\pi/4),$

$\displaystyle |(\sin ~a) ~- ~(\sin ~b)| 
~= ~2\left|\left(\sin\frac{a - b}{2}\right) ~\left(\cos\frac{a + b}{2}\right)\right|$

$\displaystyle \leq ~2\left|\left(\sin\frac{a - b}{2}\right) \right|$

$\displaystyle = ~2 \times \left(\sin ~\left|\frac{a - b}{2}\right|\right)
~< ~\text{[by Lemma 6]} ~|a - b|.$

---

WLOG $~x ~< ~y.$ 
Set $\displaystyle ~\delta = \min\left[\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \times \epsilon/2\right), ~\left(\pi/4\right)\right] 
~\implies \frac{\delta}{\pi/4} ~< ~(\epsilon/2).$

Note that $~\forall ~x, ~f(x) ~= ~f(-x). ~$ Assume that $~|x - y| ~< ~\delta.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~~x ~< ~0 ~\leq ~y}$ 
$|f(x) - f(y)| ~\leq ~|f(x) - f(0)|  ~+ |f(0) - f(y)|~$ 
$= ~|f(-x) - f(0)| ~+ ~|f(0) - f(y)|.$ 
By Lemma 5, each of the two terms in the line above is $~< ~\delta.$ 
Therefore, their sum is less than $~\epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~~x ~= ~0 ~< ~y}$ 
By Lemma 5, $~|f(x) - f(y)| ~< ~\delta ~< ~\epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~~0 ~< ~x ~< ~\pi/4 ~~~~ 
\text{and} ~~~~x ~< ~y}$ 
Let $~\alpha ~= ~(y - x) ~\implies ~\alpha ~< ~\delta.$ 
Then, by Lemma 4, 
$~|f(x) - f(y)| ~= ~J_x(\alpha) ~+ ~\alpha ~< ~\alpha ~< ~\delta ~< ~\epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 4:} ~~\pi/4 ~\leq ~x ~< ~y}$ 
Let $~\alpha ~= ~(y - x) ~\implies ~\alpha ~< ~\delta.$

$\displaystyle |f(x) - f(y)| ~= ~\left|\frac{\sin ~x}{x} ~- ~\frac{\sin ~y}{y}\right|$

$\displaystyle = ~\left|\frac{\sin ~x}{x} ~- \frac{\sin ~x}{y} ~+ \frac{\sin ~x}{y} ~- ~\frac{\sin ~y}{y}\right|$

$\displaystyle \leq ~\left|\frac{\sin ~x}{x} ~- \frac{\sin ~x}{y}\right| ~+ ~\left|\frac{\sin ~x}{y} ~- ~\frac{\sin ~y}{y}\right|.$

Using Lemma 6,

$\displaystyle ~ \left|\frac{\sin ~x}{x} ~- \frac{\sin ~x}{y}\right| ~= \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right) ~|\sin ~x|$

$\displaystyle < ~\left(\frac{y - x}{xy}\right) \times (x) ~= ~\frac{\alpha}{y} ~< ~\frac{\delta}{\pi/4} ~< ~\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Using Identy 7,

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{\sin ~x}{y} ~- ~\frac{\sin ~y}{y}\right| ~= ~\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \times \left|\sin ~x ~- ~\sin ~y\right|$

$\displaystyle < ~\left(\frac{1}{\pi/4}\right) \times (\alpha) ~< ~\frac{\delta}{\pi/4} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Thus, $~|f(x) - f(y)| ~< ~\epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 5:} ~~x ~< ~y ~\leq ~0}$ 
Since $~f(x) = f(-x), ~|f(x) - f(y)| ~= ~|f(-x) - f(-y)| .$ 
Therefore, Case 5 is proven by Cases 2 through 4, collectively.