# Prove that this piece-wise function is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x)=0 $    if $x=0$ and

$f(x)=\frac{sinx}{x}$ otherwise

I am trying to prove that this is uniformly continuous on Real numbers.

I know I need to separate the intervals and show that $\frac{sinx}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on each segment, but am having trouble since it is a piece wise function.

Comment: If you want it to be continuous, choose $f(0)=1$…

Comment: I was thinking this, but this is the problem in my text.

Comment: A typo? Or a new theorem (uniformly continous functions are discontinuous at origin)?

Comment: Yeah. I am going to go with typo. So if f(0) = 1. So I need to split R into three intervals and prove U.C. in each interval?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436825/determine-whether-fx-sin-x-over-x-is-uniformly-continuous-in-mathbb-r

Comment: @RaziehNoori Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :)