# What are different possible ways of proving that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

My main preoccupation is to find different Method to prove that the function

$$ f :x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.
 Particularly I am not able to prove it direct using the $\epsilon-\delta $ definition .
 Here What is I found so far. Since $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty $
 we conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-does-the-existence-of-a-limit-imply-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous/2399462#2399462)
But I believe that there are others ways to overcome this this issue.

Edit: Note that I am asking different possible way to to prove the uniform continuity of $f.$

Comment: It is not defined over $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore cannot be uniformly continuous over it...

Comment: we have  at $f(0)=1$

Comment: Differentiate, note that the derivative is bounded, and conclude that $f$ is even Lipschitz-continuous.

Comment: @JessePFrancis  My Question completely different from what you are suggesting . how do you find duplicate? Please red carefully

Comment: This question is wrongly marked as duplicate because the accepted answer to the other thread is that a continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous. This answer is irrelevant here as ${\mathbb R}$ is not compact.

Comment: They should be more careful. Observe that the message above says 'if those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question'. In this case, the other answer does not at all address the question, but there is no point in asking a new question, because it is not a duplicate!

Comment: Perhaps a better choice for duplicate would be [Determine whether $f(x)=\sin x/x$ is uniformly continuous in $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436825/determine-whether-fx-sin-x-over-x-is-uniformly-continuous-in-mathbb-r)

Comment: @Joffan Thanks. It's indeed a duplicate of that one. I've changed the target to it.

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice the (0,1) bit in the question I tagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One has
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \int_0^1 \cos(x t)\,d t$$
hence
$$
\left|f^\prime(x)\right| = \left |\int_0^1 t \sin(x t)\,dt\right | \le\int_0^1t\,d t \le \frac{1}{2}
$$
hence
$$\forall x, y\quad |f(x) - f(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$$

Comment: This is a more elegant proof

Answer (score 2):

For an intuitive approach: Note that we always have the mean value inequality 
$$
\bigg |\frac{\sin x}{x}-\frac{\sin y}{y}\bigg|\leq\sup_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\bigg|\frac{c\cos c-\sin c}{c^2}\bigg||x-y|
$$
but the right hand side is clearly finite. The only interesting part is near $c=0$, where we might be concerned we have a blow up. Here, Taylor expansions show us derivative is roughly 1.